# Can the three dimensional analogue of a cross cap exist without exotic matter?

Tags: general-relativity, topology, exotic-matter

Let us topologically construct the 3D analogue of a [Cross-cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cap). What we start with 3D euclidean space, and then remove a solid torus. This torus will have an axis of symmetry. We glue each point on the boundary of the resulting space (which will be in the shape of torus) to the point you get from rotating 180 degrees around the axis of symmetry (which will also be on the boundary). This will cause the surface to be non-orientable, since you change orientation when you go through the torus.

Notice in particular that this does not enable faster than light travel or time travel, since the torus doesn't teleport you to another torus (which could be far away or in the past), but just to another point on the same torus.

My question is, could this anomaly exist and be stable without using exotic matter?

Comment: Spaces with crosscaps aren't locally euclidian at the intersection, hence they are not manifolds nor spacetimes.

Comment: @Slereah well, I imagine it wouldn't be directly glued, but that would be a small, negatively corned curved "glue space", similar to how the mouths of wormholes are glued together. Note in particular that I am only specifying the **topology**, not the *geometry*, of the surface.

Comment: Write down the metric (or define it numerically, not easy how), and since you made it continuous and presumably differentiable calculate the Riemman and Rici tensors and you'll see what matter you need. I don't know if there is some kind of general treatment of what kind of global aspect,s of tHe Ricci tEnsor might be needed to make the folding you made, I've not seen such a thing but maybe there's something there. We do know that wormholes need Ricci Tensors that represent exotic matter (negative energy density or some other things), maybe there is some general property that may be found.

Comment: The problem is not in the use of exotic matter, but in the non-orientability of the manifold, which makes it impossible to have normal, fermionic matter on it.